# IntelliJ IDEA: move caret to end of word

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

(running MacOS)

I'm used to option+left/right arrow moving the caret to the end of the word. In IntelliJ it instead moves to the next word, see below example.

[image]

If I'd press option+right arrow, the caret would move to below position:
[image]

Can I somehow configure IntelliJ so that it moves to below position instead?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 [introduces](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211369) the following new options for the **Caret Movement** (File | Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General):

[image: File | Settings | Editor | General]

Set the "When moving by words" option to "Always jump to word end".

Comment: Thanks! The behaviour I was looking for seems to be default now, FYI. In other words, updating to 2019.2 is enough.

Comment: Whereas, if you want the old (pre-2019.2) behavior, choose "Always jump to word start".